# GoogleAppengineLauncher sign in fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I am trying to deploy my python AppEngine project. So, as I have done many times before for other projects, I open the GoogleAppengineLauncher, select my project, click Deploy, and enter my email and password. Then I get an error that says `Fail. Auth error.` Then when I click on the provided link for `Sign-in Failed`, it took me right to my Google account: so apparently my credentials are correct. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I have the latest version of GoogleAppengineLauncher. And yes, I am using GoogleAppengineLauncher as opposed to Terminal. Any ideas how to fix this problem? I have a mac osx-mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security?ref=home) under Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps -> Settings make sure its set to enabled.

Otherwise you will have to use the console.