# Why is the Google App Engine SDK for Windows flagged as a security risk by Google?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using app engine for windows and when I try to deploy the app to the cloud, I'm asked for a username and password. When I enter the username and password, I get the following error:

> Password for xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx: Invalid username or password.
>   2014-11-06 18:48:41,628 ERROR appcfg.py:2417 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: > > > Unauthorized. Aborting. 
>   Error 401: --- begin server output ---
>   Must authenticate first.
>   --- end server output ---
>   2014-11-06 18:48:41 (Process exited with code 1)

Then, I got an email from Google stating, that an attempt was made to login my account and it was blocked. If it wasn't me, take the following steps. But, if it was me:

> If this was you
>   You can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail to access your account (recommended) or      > change your settings at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your   >account is no longer protected by modern security standards.

Any ideas? I'd hate to lower my security standards. Is this some sort of bug?

Answer (score 1):

Use [OAuth2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2) rather than a username and password to authenticate when uploading your app.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are hitting the same [issue as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26785882/3877822).

As I told him there:

Go here under Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps -> Settings make sure its set to enabled.

Otherwise you will have to use the console.

Answer (score 0):

You might be accessing google servers via some proxy. And google being a LOCATION geek, over-intelligently blocks you. Try authenticating it once, and it should not be a problem from then on, provided proxy or IP addresses does not change frequently. NOTE: i might be completely wrong as well.